# Change logos with animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have two logos for my website which I change after the user scrolls. I noticed that the [Gamespot](http://www.gamespot.com/) adds a little animation to this. How can I achieve the same result? Either with CSS3 or jQuery

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Also providing an online demo on jsfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: @HashemQolami Sorry, I couldn't post a fiddle at the time. I was busy. Now that I see dwreck08's fiddle, I think his will demonstrate all I did + the comment I added to his answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like the following:
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shxotcc9/1/)

You can achieve it using a mix of Jquery's `scrollTop` and CSS3 transitions.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. My current code basically is hiding one image and showing the other on scroll. I basically have used what you've suggested. However, I don't know which transition to use :( I tried changing the `min-height` but it wasn't smooth enough